# Apache 404 with specific port

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, port

I have a LAMP server and I have to use a port other than 80.
I set "Listen 3689" and I didn't remove "Listen 80".
When I use the port 80 everything works fine but when I try the other one I got 404.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add a virtual host with the port you want

usually there is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Now you need to add

```
<VirtualHost *:3689>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```